# How to stop every action in a GameScene in Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I am writing a game using Swift3 and Xcode8 for iOS Platform.

I have added a button into GameScene which goes to a homePageViewController that does not include SpriteKit framework when the button is clicked. Then, I am going back to GameScene from homePageViewController, and so on.

Everything is fine so far, but when I repeat that process multiple times, GameScene starts to become laggy because when I go back to homePageViewController, GameScene and it's infinite loop update function keeps running even the user was in the Home Page.

I am using Segue Identifier for the back button and I am curious that is there any way to stop and reset every action in GameScene when back button is clicked?

Or simply in other words, when the user passed another page from GameScene, how can i make GameScene stop? It keeps running on the background.

Note: I am not asking for removeAllActions, removeAllChildren and removeFromParent functions. I am asking how to entirely stop update function.

Comment: if the view is not in your hierarchy, the skscene will not be running.  Sounds to me like you are making multiple view controllerswhen you keep going back and forth

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I have two view controllers, one is GameViewController which is for GameScene, and the second is MainPageViewController which is for another view that I made for Home Page. The button I mentioned in the question is in GameViewController and references to MainPageViewController.

I didn't get what you mean by hierarchy, but I will glad if you can help me with the problem :)

Comment: you may think you have 2 view controllers, but you may be a mad scientist making clone after clone

Comment: @Knight0fDragon can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon as you said, I am going back and forth, unfortunately your telling doesn't help me. If you know the solution, please can you tell it?

Comment: How do I have any idea on what you are doing, you have no code posted, I am talking in hypotheticals

Comment: @Knight0fDragon are you saying that in default, should GameScene's update function stop working when the user passed another view?

Comment: if the view is not in the view controller drawing hierarchy,  it shouldn't be updating.  This would mean that the view controller is not a child of your root view controller.  No idea what you are doing though, for all I know you could be doing pop over after pop over

Comment: May be your deinit is not called if you have some strong reference. You can try to use a new SKScene with no code, only a white screen. After put the func deinit inside the new scene.swift. Check If deinit is called, and if the update func is not called